# disabling/enabling checkboxes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, radio-button, struts

I have trouble making my code work. I have two radio buttons : "Anywhere" "Somewhere" and two checkboxes "Author" "Reference"
If anywhere is selected, then the two checkboxes are disabled 
If somewhere is selected, then the two checkboxes are enabled.

```
<s:radio id="search_Anywhere" name="emplacement" list="getAnywhere()"/>
<s:radio id="search_Somewhere" name="emplacement" list="getEmplacementNonPartout()"/>
<s:checkbox cssClass="list_check" name="emplacementAuthor" disabled="true" value="true"/>Author
<s:checkbox cssClass="list_check" name="emplacementreference" disabled="true" value="true"/>reference
```

I have modified the Jquery to this :

```
$("input[name='emplacement']").click(function() {
        if ($('#search_Anywhere').is (":checked" )) {
            $(".list_check").attr( "disabled" , true );
            $(".list_check").removeAttr('checked');
            } else if ($('#search_Somewhere').is (":checked" )){
                $(".list_check").removeAttr ("disabled");
                $(".list_check").attr('checked','true');
             }
            });
```

However, only the button "Somewhere" works, when I click on it enables the checkboxes.  The button "Anywhere doesn't work, which makes it impossible to disable the checkboxes one enabled.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Try using disabled instead of true `$(".list_check").attr("disabled", "disabled");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("input[name='emplacement']").click(function() {
        if ($('#search_Anywhere').is (":checked" )) {
            $(".list_check").attr( "disabled" , "disabled");
            $(".list_check").removeAttr('checked');
            } else if ($('#search_Somewhere').is (":checked" )){
                $(".list_check").removeAttr ("disabled");
                $(".list_check").attr('checked','checked');
             }
            });
```

Comment: I have tried the above but unfortunately didn't solve the problem.  Now both buttons do not work.  Checkboxes are set to disabled and it is impossible to enable them.

Comment: Are they mutually exclusive radio buttons?

Comment: Did a change in the script, can you please check if this works now?